# What am I doing wrong with my deployed connection string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

I’m having a problem with my connection string after deploying.  My site, www.coopersystems.net, is hosted by Godaddy.   I’m using Visual Web Developer Express 2012 using E-Code First. Godaddy gave me the following connection string information:

```
 Data Source=MyDatabaseName.db.10000000.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName; User ID=MyDatabaseName; Password='MyDatabasePassword';
```

I then used this info to change my connection string to the following:

```
 <connectionStrings>

  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabaseName.db. 10000000.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog = MyDatabaseName; User ID=MyDatabaseName; Password=’MyDayabasePassword’;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabaseName.db. 10000000.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog = MyDatabaseName; User ID=MyDatabaseName; Password='MyDatabasePassword';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

The default page shows up fine but clicking on the tabs that should load other pages does not work.  The page seems to hang for a while then the error page shows with error:  “We’re sorry, we’ve hit an unexpected error. Click here it you’d like to go back and try again”.

My first question is:

1: If my connection string is wrong, would my default page still load?  I ask this because when I tried changing keyword/value the home page would not load.

2:  Is there something other than my connection string that I may be able to check?

3:  How can I solve this problem?

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  I’m going on my second week of trying to get Godaddy to help and using their forums.  Nothing has worked yet.

Latest attempts:
So I fixed the password quotes and had godaddy  configured the config file to show the error message..

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I assume the server not found to mean that I provided the wrong name for a server on the Web Publish wizard so I’ve been trying different combinations of Server Name, Site Path, and Destination URL.. I got the site deployed with a few combinations of those values but the links still wont work.

Is there a configuration that maybe I should’ve done before using the “Publish” function of Web Developer Express 2012?  I am out of ideas and Godaddy can’t help.

After one week of trying I decided to try to connect to the database using IIS 7.5.  I can't connect with this either so I guess If I can solve connecting to the site or database with IIS I should be able to solve my other problems.  Please help if you can.  Thanks.

Comment: Connection string is only use if a page needs to access database. In other words, if your home page doesn't need database, it won't access database. Another thing is Password should not have Quotes `'xxx'`; it should be `Password=MyDatabasePassword;`

Comment: You really need to get the real error message, "We’re sorry, we’ve hit an unexpected error. Click here it you’d like to go back and try again" isn't going to cut it. Try to see if GoDaddy has error logging that you can see on the web server, or install something like [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) into your project to catch the unhandled excpetions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that my ISP is blocking port 1433.  No mater what I do I can't access the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the single quotes around the password:

```
Password=MyDatabasePassword
```

Comment: Removed the quotes...still nothing.